# Dell Poweredge 1550 boot from USB or CDRom

Tags: centos, dell, boot, usb

I am trying to get a dell power edge 1550 to boot off cd or USB so I can install CentOs. I created a CD with a CentOs ISO on it but the system won't recognize it. Even when I set the settings to only boot from CDrom. I then used UNetbootin to create a USB thumb however that didn't work either because their is no way to set the system to boot from USB.

The USB is turned on under integrated devices but it won't allow me to select it in the boot from menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're out of luck with the USB stick.  That server is old enough that it does not support boot from USB.

I imagine that your CD didn't burn as bootable - did you burn the ISO image to the CD as a data disk, or actually burn the ISO to the CD as the entirety of the file system?

Comment: Im slapping myself right now.